# Find the frequency with weight

Tags: r

I have following data with dates:

```
item,Date
camera,10/12/2017
mobile,10/12/2017
mobile,15/12/2017
camera,15/12/2017
mobile,15/12/2017
mobile,15/12/2017
mobile,25/12/2017
mobile,25/12/2017
camera,25/12/2017
camera,25/12/2017
camera,05/01/2018
laptop,05/01/2018
laptop,05/01/2018
computer,05/01/2018
```

Now i want to find the item frequency on the basis of date with dynamic weight.
Dynamic weight means : latest date will have 1 weight, next date(lesser then latest) should have less than 10% weight of latest date etc...
for Example:

I have 4 dates in above dataset. So weight should be:

```
Date        Weight
05/01/2018  1
25/12/2017  .90 (1 - 10% of 1)  
15/12/2017  .81 (.90 - 10% of .90)
10/12/2017  0.729 (.81 - 10% of .81)
```

New data set should be like below one:

```
item,Date           Weight
camera,10/12/2017   0.729
mobile,10/12/2017   0.729
mobile,15/12/2017   0.81
camera,15/12/2017   0.81
mobile,15/12/2017   0.81
mobile,15/12/2017   0.81
mobile,25/12/2017   0.90
mobile,25/12/2017   0.90
camera,25/12/2017   0.90
camera,25/12/2017   0.90
camera,05/01/2018   1.0
laptop,05/01/2018   1.0
laptop,05/01/2018   1.0
computer,05/01/2018 1.0
```

Comment: What date is this: `25/15/2017`? And this one, `15/15/2017`?

Comment: Try something before asking for code. Look up `dplyr` and try `group_by` using `date` as the criteria...but first you need to convert your dates to real date fields you have 15/15/2017...R will not recognize that as a date....it can see it as categorical data, but still I would be concerned about how your data read in....

Comment: Sorry date was wrong mentioned, i corrected. Date is in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution with `rle`, `seq_along` and `inverse.rle`:

```
df <- df[order(df$Date, decreasing = TRUE),]

rl <- rle(as.character(df$Date))
rl$values <- seq_along(rl$values) - 1

df$weights <- 0.9 ^ inverse.rle(rl)
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df[order(df$Date),]
>        item       Date weights
> 1    camera 2017-12-10   0.729
> 2    mobile 2017-12-10   0.729
> 3    mobile 2017-12-15   0.810
> 4    camera 2017-12-15   0.810
> 5    mobile 2017-12-15   0.810
> 6    mobile 2017-12-15   0.810
> 7    mobile 2017-12-25   0.900
> 8    mobile 2017-12-25   0.900
> 9    camera 2017-12-25   0.900
> 10   camera 2017-12-25   0.900
> 11   camera 2018-01-05   1.000
> 12   laptop 2018-01-05   1.000
> 13   laptop 2018-01-05   1.000
> 14 computer 2018-01-05   1.000
> ```

What this does:

- With `df[order(df$Date, decreasing = TRUE),]` you order your dataframe from the most recent date to the oldest date. If your date column isn't in date-format yet, convert it with `df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, '%d/%m/%Y')` first.
- With `rl <- rle(as.character(df$Date))` you create a run-length ecoding of the dates. To see what this does, look at the output of `rle(as.character(df$Date))`.
- Replace the values of the `rle`-object with `seq_along(rl$values) - 1`
- Now you can calculate the weights with `0.9 ^ inverse.rle(rl)`.

Comment: Thanks @Jaap. It works. Can you please let me know the function to find the frequency of item on the basis of weight. Can you please provide me the good tutorial to learn R?

Comment: @Ankur For the frequency: `aggregate(as.character(weights) ~ weights, df, length)`. You can find a good overview of resources at the [info-page of the R-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).

Comment: Your solution is providing me the frequency of weight but I need the frequency of item on the basis of weigh